# How to add wind speed and direction to an iphone app development?

Tags: xcode, performance, ios4, direction

I am designing an iphone app where i need the wind direction and speed adding to it, please can someone help me or send me a link to some tutorials on how to do this or what code to use.

This would be fantastic help for me and i look forward to your response.

Kind Regards

James

Answer (score 0):

You will want to find a RSS feed to get current information about the weather. Then use NSXML parser to parse the RSS feed into objects. You can google both of those to find out more.

Here is a good place to find RSS feeds for weather:
http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

And here is a good tutorial on how to parse RSS feeds.
http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html